# how do i launch java coding from atom so that it opens the entire program from github in the terminal

Tags: java, linux, github, atom-editor

So I'm working on a project as an intern and it involves atom and Github so I pulled the coding down to my desktop and have all of that set up. So how do I launch the code so that it will allow me to test the code?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make sure you have Java install on your machine, and the move into your directory, then compile the program by doing `javac filename.java` This should be the file with the main method in it. That will generate a class file, then you can just do `java filename`.

Alternatively, you could download `Eclipse` and import the project in and run the test in the IDE. This would also allow you to write your own tests, or modify them if you need. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and the `Neon` version will probably work fine for you.